# The deletion of file is not getting reflected in the project file

Tags: visual-studio

The deletion of file is not getting reflected in the project file. It shows no difference when compared.

We are using VS 2017 and TFS 2017. Project is having both C++ and C#.

Comment: How did you delete files?

Comment: From solution explorer

Comment: From solution explorer, right click and delete. After deleting file when I compare the proj file with latest version from tfs, there are no difference its showing.

Comment: Is the file you try to delete under source control? Do you open your project in TFS workspace? Are you able to see pending changes in Source Control Explorer?

Comment: Yes, file is in source control and opened in tfs workspace. Even I can see pending changes in team explorer.

Comment: Is the local project file updated after the deletion if you check it manually?

Comment: No, it is not getting updated post delete.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test on my side by deleting a file in solution explorer. Then in Source Control Explorer I could see the pending changes as the screenshot below:

[image]

**Make sure you have saved the project** (otherwise, you can not see the difference), and then compare the .csproj file between server and local.

Comment: I have done exactly the same way. See the screenshots, proj file has to get updated in couple of places however it is getting update in one place only. Please see the screenshots uploaded.

Comment: can u suggest plz

Comment: I mean to say .csproj. I have uploaded the screenshots.

Comment: Yes, I have saved the file.("Could you explain "proj file has to get updated in couple of places however it is getting update in one place only"?) when I compare .csproj file, its should remove "compile include" tag, which is happening. When I scroll down in same file it should also remove "page include" tag for valueunitscontrol.xaml file which is not happening. (ValueUnitsControl.xaml was file which I was deleted)

Comment: It seems your issue is not related to TFS, but your local project. You may create a new project to perform the same operation to see whether you can reproduce this issue.